# Php displays wrong time

Tags: php

I have a php script that collects data with the current timestamp.

The timestamp in the mysql database is correct (giving the correct time and date), although on the front end it displays : **in 5 hours**

The script that generates this output looks like this:

```
function plural($num) {
    if ($num != 1)
    return "s";
}

function relative_date($date) {
    $diff = time() - strtotime($date);
    if ($diff>0) {
        if ($diff<60)
            return $diff . " second" . plural($diff) . " ago";
        $diff = round($diff/60);
        if ($diff<60)
            return $diff . " minute" . plural($diff) . " ago";
        $diff = round($diff/60);
        if ($diff<24)
            return $diff . " hour" . plural($diff) . " ago";
        $diff = round($diff/24);
        if ($diff<7)
            return $diff . " day" . plural($diff) . " ago";
        $diff = round($diff/7);
        if ($diff<4)
            return $diff . " week" . plural($diff) . " ago";
        return date("M j, Y", strtotime($date));
    } else {
        if ($diff>-120)
            return "Right now";
        if ($diff>-60)
            return "in " . -$diff . " second" . plural($diff);
        $diff = round($diff/60);
        if ($diff>-60)
            return "in " . -$diff . " minute" . plural($diff);
        $diff = round($diff/60);
        if ($diff>-24)
            return "in " . -$diff . " hour" . plural($diff);
        $diff = round($diff/24);
        if ($diff>-7)
            return "in " . -$diff . " day" . plural($diff);
        $diff = round($diff/7);
        if ($diff>-4)
            return "in " . -$diff . " week" . plural($diff);
        return date("M j, Y", strtotime($date));
    }
}
```

How can I get that to show me the correct time?

Comment: Maybe you can clearify what you are trying, what is going wrong, what error messages you are getting etc.

Comment: Can you also include the value for $date?

Comment: The usual way to fix stuff like this is called debugging. Use an example value and look how it is processed step by step until you find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what the problem is, maybe timezone settings. Check them in your PHP.ini and in your code

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Very helpful. However I found out that the php.ini settings were set to Europe/Berlin.

Comment: @JohnBernard: as I said, wrong timezone. So my answer is correct, after all ;)